# Injecting service directly into template

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is it possible to access a service directly from an expression in a template, such as inside an ngClick? I didn't think it was possible, but Angular material's Menu demo seems to inject a custom service `$mdOpenMenu` as easily as injecting $event into the expression: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu

Comment: `$event` is a special case. It is available in dom event directives (like ng-click, ng-mouseenter , ng-change etc) as an argument and represents the actual event object. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [source for the menu controller](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/menu/js/menuController.js#L106), the menu directive causes `$mdOpenMenu` to be assigned to the scope of the markup within that directive, so `$mdOpenMenu` is available within the markup and can be passed to functions. It isn't a service in the traditional Angular sense. It is just a function that the directive's controller added to the scope.